# JAR created with maven having resources directly placed in JAR

Tags: java, maven, resources, pom.xml, log4j2

I am creating a JAR using maven plugin. But all the files places inside the `src/main/resources` folder are being directly placed inside the JAR, rather than the **resources** folder. (resources folder is not being created inside JAR at all)

Due to which the application which is using JAR is not able to find log4j2.xml file. Earlier resources folder was being created, but now somehow it's not being created.

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <codehaus.mojo.version>1.11</codehaus.mojo.version>
        <log4j.version>2.11.1</log4j.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.assembly.plugin.version>2.4.1</maven.assembly.plugin.version>
        <maven.resources.plugin.version>2.6</maven.resources.plugin.version>
        <sonar.maven.plugin.version>3.3.0.603</sonar.maven.plugin.version>
        <artifactory.maven.plugin.version>2.6.1</artifactory.maven.plugin.version>
        <eclipse.lifecycle.mapping.version>1.0.0</eclipse.lifecycle.mapping.version>
        <junit.platform.surefire.provider.version>1.0.1</junit.platform.surefire.provider.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.19.1</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <codehaus.mojo.maven.plugin.version>1.6.0</codehaus.mojo.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
    <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>

                <directory>src</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.assembly.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>package.Test</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${artifactory.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${codehaus.mojo.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java.version}</source>
                            <target>${java.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${codehaus.mojo.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>package.Test</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit.platform.surefire.provider.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <!-- This is added to ignore error in life cycle of aspectj-maven-plugin 
            due to bug in m2eclipse -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>${eclipse.lifecycle.mapping.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>${codehaus.mojo.version}</version>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Project Structure:**

```
Project
    -----src/main/java
    -----src/main/resources
                 log4j2.xml
    -----src/test/java
```

**Jar Structure :**

```
Jar
  -----log4j2.xml
```

In the application console I ma getting message:

> ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation.
>   Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to
>   the console...

Comment: The first thing your pom looks like you haven't realized the convention of configuration paradigm ...you should keep the location for source (production code) `src/main/java` for resources you should use `src/main/resources` which is packaged into the resulting jar file. If you need to have a directory in the resulting jar file for the log4j2.xml file simply add that directory into `src/main/resources` directory. Furthermore remove manually binding maven-compiler-plugin to the life cycle..remove configuration of provider in maven-surefire-plugin (that's handled by surefire itself)...

Comment: The `resources` directory should not being part of the jar file ..cause convention is to have resources usually in the root of the jar file ...or more generally on the classpath...

Comment: Please try once by removing   <resource>                 <directory>src</directory>             </resource>

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with the log4j2.xml files several times myself. First of all: maven is doing the right thing, by placing that XML file into the root of the JAR - which is exactly, where it belongs ([link to docs - look at "Automatic Configuration" point 9](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)).

Now, as Log4j2 does apparently not find the logging configuration, some things are going wrong.

These could be:

- there is a syntax error in your config file
- your logging file makes declarations, that Log4J is not able to resolve (e.g. using a specific logger that can't be found on the classpath)
- one or more of your dependencies also have a similarly named log4j2.xml file at the root of your dependencie's jar file. In that case, there is an ambiguity, that Log4J can't resolve at runtime
- when you run your application, you've explicitly specified where log4j should be looking for that file.

in some cases, you might get a hint from log4j about what has happened. Anyways, I would suggest, you start your application with a `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` parameter. That will cause Log4J to print out internal debugging information which will give you some more hints about what is going on. (If you don't know how to use `-D` params, be sure to look it up, as their positioning can be a bit tricky. If not put at the right place of the script execution, they'll get ignored)

I hope, that helps you to specify the problem. If not, it would be super helpful, to add the console output of your application to the question. Ideally with debug output on.

Comment: But same file is logging correctly when I am using it from eclipse main class. But I will try with -Dlog4j2.debug=true.

Comment: Yes, that's a typical issue. In that case, it might be related to the classpath of your application when it's not running within eclipse. How is that application started otherwise?

Comment: Application is started using .bat file, where this jar is added in dependency. Some how few days back it was working for me.

Comment: can you paste the bat file's contents?

Comment: That bat file trigger fantom (a programming language) code, so it's a complete different way. Jar is added as POD to fantom.

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying the output folder explicitly like:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working. Thanks for the answer.